# Formatting paragraphs with Django and html

Tags: html, django

I am makeing a blog with django and i have a problom. when ever i write sevral pargraphs into my form and then print the modle on to the html page the two paragraphs gt mushed into one. If anyone knows how i can keep the paragrphs spreat that would be much appricated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the paragraphs in HTML paragraph elements.
For example:

```html
<p> Paragraph one </p>
<p> Paragraph two </p>
```

I'd recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwNC5ppZo_dYGVjerQY3xYU) YouTube series if you want to learn more about how to write HTML and CSS.

Comment: not exactly what I need but thx for trying.

Comment: Please edit your question for better clarity and tell us what you've already tried. This answer solves the question you're asking from my perspective.